# Samba is constantly writing to HDD

Tags: linux, samba

I'm running a Samba server on Raspbian and observing that Samba during idle periods is constantly (every minute) writing to HDD (maybe doing some journaling?) what causes the HDD to constantly spin and never standby:

```
root@rpi:~# pidstat -dl 20
Linux 4.4.50-v7+ (localhost)    11/07/2018  _armv7l_    (4 CPU)

04:10:08 AM   UID       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s iodelay  Command
04:10:28 AM     0       832      0.00      0.20      0.20       0  /usr/sbin/smbd -D 

04:11:08 AM   UID       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s iodelay  Command
04:11:28 AM     0       832      0.00      0.20      0.20       0  /usr/sbin/smbd -D 

04:12:08 AM   UID       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s iodelay  Command
04:12:28 AM     0       832      0.00      0.20      0.20       0  /usr/sbin/smbd -D
```

Is there some way (via configuration setting or maybe recompiling with some parameter) to turn off this constant disk io?

Comment: Is it constantly reading and serving data also? The stats don't show any reading currently, but maybe it's delayed? Does the filesystem have `atime` enabled, so writes for every file access?

Comment: @Xen I disconnected all clients from samba server and turned off all shares for the sake of test, but this behaviour - HDD write every 60 seconds - remained the same. atime is enabled, but these writes take place even without enabled shares.

Comment: Just an idea -- I see a [housekeeping_fn](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/5ab0b4af9edbd50c0c7747840f9b3aca9cb01da8/source3/smbd/process.c) that's set up to call every SMBD_HOUSEKEEPING_INTERVAL (default 60) seconds; the main point of which seems to be to reopen a log file.  You could try disabling logging or recompiling with a different value for the housekeeping interval to see if either is effective.

Comment: @Jeff Seems like the explanation of the situation. This would be the answer.

Comment: I cited your finding on Samba's mail list and one of the Samba developers said that this is likely the explanation. The housekeeping  function calls stat function for checking whether the conf file should be reloaded. This causes updating file atime and HDD write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [separately confirmed](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-November/219284.html), there is a [housekeeping function](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/5ab0b4af9edbd50c0c7747840f9b3aca9cb01da8/source3/smbd/process.c) that is called every SMBD_HOUSEKEEPING_INTERVAL (default 60) seconds; the main point of the function (to me) seems to be to reopen a log file.

The quote from the mailing list was:

> so yes it's goint to look at smb.conf and check_log_size()
>   will do an fstat() on the open log file descriptor, so this
>   may explain it.

You could disable logging or recompile with a different value for the housekeeping interval.